# I have a error on last line of index.php im not sure what it could be

Tags: php, wordpress

Hello could someone please help me I'm having trouble with my PHP being successfully compiled it says it is the last line but I think last line is right not experienced enough to know if it's right or not

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php if( have_posts() ) { ?>
    <?php while( have_posts() ) { ?>
        <?php the_post(); ?>
        <h2>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title() ?> </a>
        </h2>
} else { ?>
<p>Sorry, No post matched</p>
<?php } ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Can you please post the error as well?

Comment: Please close while loop.

Comment: Please go read [ask]. Quote error messages verbatim when asking something like this, instead of just vaguely telling us that you “have” an error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you haven't closed the while loop. and there is no opening php. you cannot do `</h2> } else { ?>`

```
<?php get_header(); ?>


<?php if(have_posts()) { ?>
    <?php while(have_posts()) { ?>
    <?php the_post(); ?>
    <h2>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title() ?> </a>
    </h2>
<?php } //while end
} else { ?>
<p>Sorry, No post matched</p>
<?php } ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

     <?php if( have_posts() ) { ?>
         <?php while( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
             <h2>
                 <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a>
             </h2>
         <?php endwhile; ?>
     <?php } else { ?>
         <p>Sorry, No post matched</p>
     <?php } ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not closes the **[while](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping.asp)** loop. Try this one:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php if(have_posts()) { ?>
    <?php while(have_posts()) { ?>
    <?php the_post(); ?>
    <h2>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title() ?> </a>
    </h2>
  <?php } // end while loop (here was you mistake) ?>
<?php } else { ?>
<p>Sorry, No post matched</p>
<?php } ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```